# What are Gourmet Vouchers?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

After dining at the Canteen several times, I received a Gourmet Voucher. Having used several Vouchers before, I know that the normal Vouchers make all the food options "fresh" and therefore more likely to activate the Felyne skills. How does a Gourmet Voucher then differ from a normal Voucher? I don't see anything *extra* that it could do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Capcom forums](http://www.capcom-unity.com/monster_hunter/go/thread/view/7451/29850445/gourmet-vouchers?post_num=5):

> Vouchers give a free meal and make all the ingredients fresh. Gourmet vouchers do this as well, and causes *all* of the skills shown to activate.

Both types of vouchers can also be used as crafting materials.